# array of objects inside a collection

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collections

I'm trying to understand how to use an array of objects together a collection, but I can't understand.

```
Dim col As New Collection

    Dim ObjArray(3) As Object
    ObjArray(0) = chapter
    ObjArray(1) = paragraph
    ObjArray(2) = voice

    collezione.Add(ObjArray)
```

This is my declaration. I don't know how many objects there are inside each field in ObjArray.
I want to do a For to check every value inside ObjArray, but how can I loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cycle through your array and add each item to the collection

```
    For position As Integer = 0 To ObjArray.Length - 1
        col.Add(ObjArray(position))
    Next
```